# Suitable build folder structure for small web apps

Tags: build, sass, gulp

Is the folder structure below suitable for small web application builds? I've just learnt Sass, and how to build system automating tasks with gulp.

From what I understand the following will happen;

- I'll work on the Sass files in the src/sass folder.. which compliles via gulp to dist/css/main.css file.
- The same will happen with src/js/ files, which concatenate into dist/js/main.js
- I work on the PHP files directly in the dist/ folder

```html
- /dist
      - index.php
      - /css
           - main.css 
      - /js
            - main.js

- /src
      - /js
          - file1.js
          - file2.js
      - /sass
          - main.sass
          - _additonal.sass
              - /vendor
                  - /bootstrap
                  - _boostrap.sass

- /docs

package.json
gulpfile.js
```

I'm after some clarification of my process, and any advice on how to improve it :) I've had a look on Stackoverflow/google but can't find anything that isn't for larger scale projects.

Comment: I wouldn't work on php files directly in the dist folder if I was you. The idea of the dist folder is that you could delete it and rebuild the site from source, without losing anything. So put them in src/, then just pipe the files directly in to dist with gulp.

Comment: That seems so obvious now that you pointed that out, thanks for the feedback. Other than that do you think I'm following the correct process?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. There's a bunch of gulp plugins you can try out, like auto-prefixer's and image minification. But they aren't particularly necessary. But from a structure standpoint you're pretty much there.

Comment: I've just added the auto-prefixer to my gulp task, it all makes a lot of sense now.